# IPad OS - Chrome / safari browser memory space was not reduced after removing data from indexed DB Database

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ipad, safari, indexeddb

In our application, we are using the browser's indexedDB storage for offline data storage. It has been working as expected in Windows/Mac Chrome browsers. However, we have encountered an issue with iPad Chrome where we are unable to use more than 900+ MB of data. We need to support storage of up to 5 GB. Interestingly, Safari on the iPad allows us to use up to 100+ GB (on the 128 GB iPad Pro variant) with user approval through a memory extension popup. Is there any way to achieve similar functionality in Chrome?

Additionally, we have observed that after removing data from the indexedDB, the memory usage in the application does not decrease. For example, if I upload 900 MB of data to the indexedDB and then proceed to remove it, I verify that the indexedDB is empty. However, when checking the storage usage on the iPad, it still shows that 900 MB of memory is being used by Chrome. It seems that the iPad's operating system does not free up the space after deleting data from the indexedDB. Is there another option or approach to free or release this memory from the browser's app usage?

We have attempted to remove the data from the indexedDB, but the memory is not released. Clearing the browser cache partially releases the memory, but we would like to handle this directly through JavaScript.

Comment: Welcome to the community @manivannan372!  A good practice when writing even just 4 paragraphs on here is to add subheadings. This really gives people nicer segments (like small bites to chew off at a time), which inclines more people to read through it, which will usually get you more answers. Have a good one.